# How do you sign a message in node, and then verify that signature came from an admin wallet in a solidity contract (for off chain whitelisting)?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to implement offchain whitelisting, where a user makes an authenticed call to my node server asking for permission to mint a token. The server will respond with a signature allowing to mint. Then the user will hit the Solidy contract with a web3 call and the signature, which will set off the mint operation and then save the signature so that it can no longer be used to mint more tokens.

Answer (score 0):

First on the server do the following:

```
// get admin wallet signer
const lastSigner = (await ethers.getSigners()).pop();
// this is the address that we will put in the contract to check against
console.log("address", lastSigner!.address);

// make a unique message who's signature will be stored to the contract
// so that it can't be used again
const msg = "" + Math.random();

// sign the message using your PK
const sig = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(msg, "PK here");

// enter these variables in the web3 call
console.log("signature", sig.signature);
console.log("messageHash", sig.messageHash);
```

in contract

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

...
   using ECDSA for bytes32;
   mapping (bytes => bool) usedWhitelistSigs;


   address private adminWalletAddress = <ADMIN WALLET THAT SIGNS ON SERVER HERE>;
...

function verifySig(bytes32 messageHash, bytes memory signature)  public returns (bool) {
    require(!usedWhitelistSigs[signature], "Signature already used to mint");

    address signingAddress = ECDSA.recover(messageHash, signature);
    console.log(signingAddress);
        
    // verify that the message hash was signed by the admin wallet addreess
    bool valid = signingAddress == adminWalletAddress;
    
    require(valid, "Invalid signature");

    usedWhitelistSigs[signature] = true;

    return valid;
    }
```

todo: store hash so it can't be used